# How do you replace all classes in a project with another class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Migrates in a project from the `Date` class to the `Instant` class, which is recommended for Java 8. The Date class I have used in the project 80 times.  [image]

Is there any way, all use of the `Date` class type to be replaced with the `Instant` class type?

Change the `Date` class to `Instant`

Change `new Date` to `Instant.now()`

Change import `java.util.Date` to  `java.date.Instant`

I use IntellIJ. I am looking for a way that I do not have to do it manually 80 times. Is there an automatic way for a substitute?

Comment: If you're willing to CLI, `sed -i 's/new Date()/Instant.now()/g' *.java` and then likewise for the rest.

Comment: @merlin2011 What about imports?

Comment: [Migration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrate.html) refactoring may help.

Comment: @shmosel, Any reason to believe you couldn't do the corresponding substitution for imports?

Comment: @merlin2011 I suppose not.

Comment: I am new to Intellij. I can not find what a CLI is. Is this a Command Line Tool Support plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA provides the [Migrate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/migrate.html) refactoring.

> The Migrate refactoring allows you to easily switch between the old
>   packages and classes used in your project and the new ones.

Comment: And will it replace the ```new Date``` with ```Instant.now()```?

Comment: You can use [SSR](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html) or basic Find/Replace for that.